# Study of a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I'm asked to study everything that is possible to know about the sytem$$\begin{cases}x'=x^2-y^2\\y'=2xy\\z'=-z\end{cases}$$

My questions here is, how much can be know about it?, how do I know I finished?

I found the equilibrium points of the system

$$x'=0\iff x^2-y^2=0\iff |x|=|y|\\y'=0\iff (x=0)\vee(y=0)\\z'=0\iff z=0$$

I conclude that the only equilibrium point if the origin. Now I try to find the equilibria of the origin, since the system is non-linear I use the Lyapunov function $V(x,y,z)=ax^2+by^2+cz^2$ which is definite positive if $a,b,c>0$.

Now $\nabla V\cdot f$ gives $$\nabla V\cdot f=2ax(x^2-y^2)+2by(2xy)+2cz(-z)=2ax^2-xy^2(4b-2a)-2cz^2.$$ I''m up to finding constants to help me to determine the equilibria of the origin, if I'm right it will be given by

$$\begin{cases}\nabla V\cdot f \leq 0 &\text{stable}\\\nabla V\cdot f <0 & \text{asymptoticalle stable}\\\nabla V \cdot f>0 & \text{unstable}\end{cases}$$

The first one seem to be the case. I thought that a valid choice would be $a=b=c=1$; then there is a boundary in which $x^2-2xy^2-2z^2\leq 0$, a ball of a radius smaller than $1$ seem to work here: if $v\in B_{1/2}(0)$ then $x,y,z<1/2$ and $x^2-2xy^2-2z^2<(1/2)^2-2(1/2)(1/2)^2-2(1/2)^2=-(1/2)^2<0$ and the origin is stable.
I can't tell if the origin is asymptotically stable.

If I'm supposed to study the system, what else can I say about it?

Comment: Can't you reduce this to a system of two equations given that $z$ is decoupled from the other equations and is solved as $z(t) = c_1 e^t$? (Unless there is a typo and it is missing in other equations). It looks like you can also find a closed-form solution to validate all of the analysis.

Comment: @Amzoti:  got your signifiant email.  Been busy; will respond in detail shortly.  Best Regards and Holiday Cheers!  ;-)

Comment: @Amzoti There's no typo, this time I got it right :P

You're right, but I suppose I have to linearize the system to be able to solve it?

Comment: @RobertLewis: Huh?

Comment: Using $(x+iy)'=(x+iy)^2$ you should be able to integrate the equations for $x$ and $y$ explicitly. (And $z$ is decoupled from $x$ and $y$, as was already pointed out.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Umm, could you elaborate that part? I'm not sure how to use the equality you gave me.

I tried to do as the comments said, but my approach was integrating the second function and making the subtituion in the first one. It seems to lead to a dead end: $\frac{dy}{dt}=2xy \implies \int \frac{1}{y}dy = \int 2xdt \implies \log y = 2xt \implies y=c_2 e^{2xt}$. This makes the first equation hard to solve for me, because now to have an explicit solution I should solve $\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2-c_2^2e^{4xt}$.

Comment: Just set $Z(t)=x(t)+i y(t)$. Then you get a separable ODE $dZ/dt=Z^2$.